# Sunlight-powered device set to change world: will it work?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure

Vast areas of desert sand are being shone on upon by the sun. Now that's some ENERGY!

Using this proposed apparatus:

1. Sunlight over large area is concentrated on steam chamber, where water turns into vapor.
2. The high temperatures of the gases in the steam chamber will push on the loose piston, compressing the air above it right into the air canister.
3. Air canister is carefully sealed and removed from the apparatus.

The air canisters can then be used for refrigeration, as placing them inside an insulated chamber (the "fridge" with food in it) and releasing the gas outside will significantly reduce temperatures. Repeated with enough canisters, I believe the internal temperature of the "fridge" can reach below 0 degrees Celsius temperatures?

Can some kind soul explain to me the efficiency and possible limitations of this apparatus?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with the idea.  Probably mirrors instead of lenses would be used, and probably a different, *continuous* compression scheme such as using steam to drive a turbine to power an electric air compressor.  Probably the compressed air would be stored locally and used to drive generators to provide electric power on demand.  But the basic idea is good.  The bottom-line question is whether it's more practical & profitable to store the energy in the form of compressed air, raised masses, superconducting currents, charged batteries, hydrogen, or other such energy-storage media.  The answer to *that* question is not so much in the realm of physics as in the realm of logistics, economics, and technology.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me, there is at least one solar powered plant in the U.S. that uses several acres of computer controlled mirrors to focus sunlight on a “boiler” at the top of a tower.  Heat collected by the boiler powers turbine driven generators which put electricity into the grid. (No canisters required.)

Comment: Right.  I pass several such plants when I drive between Salt Lake City and LA.